# Eclipse Windowbuilder to IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, windowbuilder

Yesterday I moved to Intellij from Eclipse. I imported all my Eclipse work-spaces to Intellij without any problems.

In my work-space I have several projects built with Windowbuilder (the Eclipse plugin for GUI design). Is there any method to load these GUI's into the GUI editor of Intellij?

Comment: No, I haven't found a way to import windowbuilder's files into Intellij. So I don't think it is possible unless lots of users request such feature or plugin to be created.